# How can I override Mandrill's utm_source header in php and Swift email for Google Analytics reporting?

Tags: php, email, google-analytics, mandrill, transactional

The documentation indicates I can change the `utm_campaign` header with

```
$headers->addTextHeader('X-MC-GoogleAnalyticsCampaign', 'my-campaign');
```

When an email sent by Mandrill is being clicked, the created URL is

```
utm_medium=email&utm_source=transactional&utm_campaign=my-campaign
```

And I correctly see "my-campaign" in Google Analytics reporting.

How can I also change the `utm_source header?

I tried this:

```
$headers->addTextHeader('X-MC-Metadata', '{"utm_source" : "my-source"}');
```

But the `utm_source` remains "transactional".

Comment: You could add an advanced filter in you Analytics account that changes the campaign source depending on the value of the campaign name. While that would be a big PITA to maintain it seems to be the only way, as the Mandrill docs state explicitly that you cannot override the source.

Comment: thanks, i will experiment with this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like editing the utm_source value [isn't supported](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582577), but you can create the tracking URLs on your own with Google's URL builder.

Comment: Yes i can, but then seems I can't send the tracking URL through Mandrill, which is what I would need.

Comment: Why not? Keep Mandrill's default click tracking enabled but disable their auto-Google Analytics tracking and generate your own manually. Should still be able to get Mandrill's default tracking applied to your manually-built analytics URL.